# Is it wrong to ask a question with many answers?

Tags: discussion, support, closed-questions, list-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List questions: Community Wiki?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98334/list-questions-community-wiki)

I'm referring to my question here: [Java optimizations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832341/java-optimizations)

I don't completely understand why it was closed. It does not violate any of the reasons stated. I am looking for concrete facts, not opinion. I don't think this question would start a large debate/argument.

The only possible reason I can find was stated in a comment by Goran Jovic:

> Anyway, your problem was most likely closed because there is no finite answer to it. It would probably spawn dozens of answers each containing a single optimization. This is usually not considered constructive because it is very easy for initial Q&A format to degrade to a poll.

Perhaps this may be true, but is it necessarily bad? I believe the answers to this question are legitimate and would be extremely helpful/constructive. This is evident in the comments again as two people learned something very useful without even a single direct answer.

I can sort of see why it was closed, but was it really necessary? I was honestly looking forward to the answers and thought others would enjoy learning something too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The close reason explains why it was closed:

> This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers
>   to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this
>   question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or
>   extended discussion.

To make Stack Overflow more of a question and answer site, and less like a forum, we choose to accept *questions that can be answered specifically and definitively.*  This greatly increases our overall signal-to-noise ratio.  https://stackoverflow.com/faq describes these rules in greater detail.

Comment: Yes I read that and addressed it in my question.

Comment: @tsk: The Q&A format is one of the fundamental principles of Stack Overflow, and is unlikely to change.  If you need a more "forum-like" format, there are many places on the Internet where that is available.  We've tried to build something better here; this requires us to be somewhat selective about the questions we can accept.

Comment: Ok that makes more sense. Thanks.

Comment: Annoyingly, the FAQ doesn't clearly address whether questions should have *definitive* answers or whether there are any (even rough) guidelines about questions with multiple or many answers.

Comment: @KennyEvitt: Questions that seek to build a list of things or questions that require a book chapter to answer are considered Too Broad.    See http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask