# Adding a wiki post of third party iOS tools

Tags: discussion

Earlier this week, there was a question posted of third party libraries that people use for iOS.  It was closed, but had lots of responses. I think there should be a wiki post that contains all of the ones recommended here to point new users too.

[Link to Question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11846753/list-of-third-party-libraries-for-ios-application-development-16-so-far#11846753)

Comment: What is the question you're talking about?

Comment: It was deleted, so I can't get to it.

Comment: You don't have a link to it anymore? >10k users most likely will still be able to see it.

Comment: Okay, updated to include question

Comment: List questions are generally considered off-topic since they have no real answer. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98334/list-questions-community-wiki

Comment: Here is the [Google Cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:stackoverflow.com/questions/11846753/list-of-third-party-libraries-for-ios-application-development-16-so-far#11846753) for anyone that is interested.

Comment: Okay, seeing as this is a poor question, and I should've read more about list questions not being on topic. Go ahead and close this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, we've found that list-style questions don't work well in the format of this site. They generally devolve into piles of dozens, if not hundreds, of answers that aren't curated well. People won't read the whole list of pages of answers, so they just keep posting duplicates and the whole thing ends up being a mess. That's why that question was closed.

Second, this question has been posed many times in the past. Two of the ones I can find right now are

- ["Open source iOS components? Reusable views, controllers, buttons, table cells, etc?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640805/open-source-ios-components-reusable-views-controllers-buttons-table-cells-e)
- ["Useful iPhone Libraries"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905407/useful-iphone-libraries)

Do we need yet another one? I suppose we could link to the above from the actual [iphone](/questions/tagged/iphone) and [ios](/questions/tagged/ios) tag wikis, to point people at these canonical questions.

Stack Overflow really isn't designed for these kinds of lists. Thankfully, there are many other places designed to host such a list, like [Cocoa Controls](http://www.cocoacontrols.com) or [Verious](http://www.verious.com/ios/), among others.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the content of the question and answers. Feel free to edit them into the appropriate tag wiki or anywhere else that is appropriate.

1. [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/) - Networking
2. [RestKit](http://restkit.org) - RESTFul api
3. [Cocos2D](http://cocos2d.org) - Game development
4. [Three20](http://three20.info) - Nice interface tools
5. [Regex kit lite](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/RegexKitLite/) - Regular expression
6. [CorePlot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/) - Very interesting
7. [ShareKit](http://www.getsharekit.com) - Very Social
8. [DCIntrospect](https://github.com/domesticcatsoftware/DCIntrospect) - Interface debugging
9. [iOS application base boiler plate code](http://iosboilerplate.com) - The best I have found so far!
10. [Tapku](http://tapku.com) - I guess this is the most popular
11. [InAppSettings](http://www.inappsettingskit.com) - Very smart
12. [Route-me](https://github.com/route-me/route-me) - Something more then a MapKit
13. [CocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket) - for working with TCP and UDP protocols
14. [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) - for working with HTTP
15. [SocketRocket](https://github.com/square/SocketRocket) - A conforming Objective-C WebSocket client library.
16. [Sharekit](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit) - Drop in sharing features for all iPhone and iPad apps
17. [SSpullToRefresh](https://github.com/samsoffes/sspulltorefresh) - Simple and highly customizable pull to refresh view
18. [SSDatakit](https://github.com/samsoffes/ssdatakit) -  Eliminate your Core Data boilerplate code

[MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) is quite useful when you need a loading indicator

[SBJson](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/) a JSON framework which is pretty useful
[FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) is also a decent wrapper for sqlite.

[UnitTWebSocket](http://code.google.com/p/unitt/wiki/UnittWebSocketClient) - Websocket client