# Are list questions off topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, question-quality, list-questions

This old question asked for "[the opinion about list questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11760/whats-the-opinion-on-list-questions)". The answers are from three years ago.

In current (July 2012) Stack Exchange, are list questions considered off topic?

By list question I mean any question that can't have a single, best answer, like this [question I asked about what tools are available to manage tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94481/what-tools-are-available-for-a-team-leader-members-to-manage-tasks-agile-prog).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Questions that ask for a list are considered not constructive, as every answer is equally valid.

Generally, those questions are infinite, as a new answer could always be added; they also tend to be subjective. As such, those questions should not be asked, basing on what written in the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask).

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.
>
> To prevent your question from being flagged and [possibly removed](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion), avoid asking subjective questions where …
>
> - every answer is equally valid: "What's your favorite ______?"
> - your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: "I use ______ for ______, what do you use?"
> - there is no actual problem to be solved: "I'm curious if other people feel like I do."
> - we are being asked an open-ended, hypothetical question: "What if ______ happened?"
> - it is a rant disguised as a question: "______ sucks, am I right?"

Comment: "those questions are infinite". That's Trumpian hyperbole, to put it politely. Sometimes they are; many times they're not. The same goes for 'subjective'. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180369/278912

Comment: And for every absurd statement on this meta meta, I can find its near opposite--like the one on 'good subjective'. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298746/good-subjective-and-knowledge-questions-vs-problems-you-face

Comment: Yes, they are infinite, because the list, given in one or more answers, should be updated every time there is a new item to be added to the list, or a previous item needs to be removed. Instead of asking for a list, the question should ask the true question behind that list request, which is what should be done either when the list is finite and will never change, or the list is not finite and should be continuously updated.

Comment: Then, this answer is for *In current (**July 2012**) Stack Exchange, are list questions considered off topic?* It is not answering for subjective questions, which are different questions, with different issues. (Subjective questions should not be confused with questions where part of a answer is subjective, though. Plus, subjective questions could be appropriate for some Stack Exchange sites, but not other Stack Exchange sites.)