# Does any site cover the concept of "Intelligence" in general, both artificial and natural?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I've been developing and working on Artificial Intelligence. I know that Stack Overflow is the place to go with programming-only questions, so I have my bases covered on that side of my AI.

However, is there a site that focuses on simply breaking down intelligence in general regardless of whether it is human or artificial?

For example, if I wanted to ask the question that I posted on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/findareddit/comments/4v4ofj/designproblemsolving_process/), "How do I further break down the process of identifying restraints on solutions and problems?" where would I ask this question?

I don't even believe that these kinds of questions are answerable by any community on Stack Exchange considering the wide adoption of the rule "*no broad or unclear topics.*"

I was only hoping to get answers to these questions from a well-educated community which Stack Exchange certainly qualifies as.

Comment: you mean [ai.SE](http://ai.stackexchange.com/)? (the Artificial Intelligence Stack Exchange Site)

Comment: I suppose that could work. Does that site cover topics not already known to those who work in AI, but is soly-related to Artificial Intelligence? and would that question be ask-able on that site (*no broad topics*)?

Comment: @Memor-X, just based on this question (http://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/2127/advantages-of-having-self-driving-cars) I am going to assume that question is askable there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already mentioned, the process of finding constraints is much too large for one question. If you can break it down into multiple more specific questions, that would be very good - it might still be a *little* subjective, but some Stack Exchange sites permit moderately open-ended questions as long as answers can be backed up by facts and references.

At [Artificial Intelligence](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), as long as a question can be applied to the construction of an AI, we welcome it. Note that the math/stats parts of implementation are off-topic and are better served on Cross Validated. (AI mod here, if our on-topic page could use clarification, please tell me.) For intelligence and cognition questions in general, [Cognitive Science](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) looks promising.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be seeking a list of "restraints on solutions and problems" so I suspect that your question, as asked on Reddit, will be off-topic on all Stack Exchange sites.

See [Are list questions off topic?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139618/are-list-questions-off-topic)

Comment: No. How does an intelligent being *produce* a list of constrainsts. Essentially, *how does list __production__ work?*