# Where do I ask the question "What does the string "scrlybrkr" do in URLs?"?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where can I ask a question like:

> What does the string "scrlybrkr" do in URLs?

It doesn't seem to fit particularly well on any of the Stack Exchange sites that I've checked.

Edit: I figured out what it was, the reason it was doing weird stuff was because of Securly(which is installed on my school Chromebook), it doesn't do much if your device doesn't have Securly.

Comment: With the information provided here, that question would be closed due to lack of detail on any Stack Exchange site.  That string doesn't _inherently_ do anything in a URL, so we'd need a lot more context.  _With_ that context, there are some sites that it _could_ be on topic on (for instance, if the question were "Why does Contoso Antivirus report an error when I open a URL with the string 'scrlybrkr' in it?", that would be on-topic on [su]), but we'd need the context to make a useful site recommendation.

Comment: Someone [asked that question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48083461/what-is-the-meaning-of-scrlybrkr-in-a-url) in 2018 and it was closed.

Comment: @smitop not only that, it is also deleted.

Comment: Dunno where you can ask, but that's most likely a "cache breaker", meant to prevent the browser from caching the page, if the value of the URL parameter is random. If it's not random, might be tracking, e.g. to know where you came from.

Comment: @rene yeah, [here is screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ne8j.png) of a useful answer, that might answer the OP here as well.

Comment: And now we are doing the human search engine thing anyway. Perhaps it should be formalised? While we are in the rabbit hole: *scrly* = [Securly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Securly)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on)

Comment: @gnat This isn't about computer science or programming, so that does not answer this question.

Comment: @RyanM is this merely your opinion or you can justify it somehow. I for one have an opinion that questions about Universal Resource Locator fall squarely into this field

Comment: @gnat Well, it's certainly not about the academic discipline of computer science.  And while questions about URLs *can* be about programming, *this* one really doesn't seem to be.  It's certainly off-topic on Stack Overflow, the site I moderate.  It's also off-topic on Web Applications (which, while not about computer science/programming, is mentioned there) unless it's about a _specific_ web application, according to a moderator there.  Basically, I don't see what site from that list you're implying it should be posted on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That question shouldn't be asked anywhere within the SE network if all you have is an observation and answers are at best trivia. [For example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48083461/what-is-the-meaning-of-scrlybrkr-in-a-url):

> it is a query string used for tracking and analytics

or

> It is a content filter for schools.

What have you and future visitors now learned? Not much useful I would argue.

If this url is used in a context where you need something solved, logged, untracked, etc it can become on-topic on several sites, depending on context. Until then you have to find a chat room or a site outside of the SE Network to get an answer for that question.

Answer (score 5):

## TL;DR: Details are required.

You are right, due to the lack of details, the "question" doesn't look to be a good fit for any Stack Exchange site.

---

## Overview

It looks that there is a misconception about what "question" means in Stack Exchange, in a *community tour*, the articles about like *How to ask a good question* from the communities' Help Centers and in mosts  meta posts that discuss the post type named *question*.

## Questions in the wild Vs SE questions

Stack Exchange is not about "questions" as they are defined in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question) (links and formatting not included)

> A question is an utterance which serves as a request for information. Questions are sometimes distinguished from interrogatives, which are the grammatical forms typically used to express them. Rhetorical questions, for instance, are interrogative in form but may not be considered bona fide questions, as they are not expected to be answered.

Someone might argue that SE questions are *requests for information* but that is not really correct as SE sites are not  *information request services* (see [digital reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_reference)). SE sites serve communities that are working together, to build a knowledge base about certain topic.

> Questions come in a number of varieties. Polar questions are those such as the English example "Is this a polar question?", which can be answered with "yes" or "no". Alternative questions such as "Is this a polar question, or an alternative question?" present a list of possibilities to choose from. Open questions such as "What kind of question is this?" allow many possible resolutions.

*Polar questions* and *alternative questions* are not allowed in any main site. It might be possible to ask a question where the answer might be  Yes or no, one option or another, but should ***invite*** to explain *why* and *how*, and never should be about trivial or non-relevant stuff (boring, short-living, helpful/interesting only to the asker or to a very narrow niche) from the point of view of the *core community*.

Considering this clasification, SE questions are *open questions* but not all of them are allowed. SE questions should be "answerable", "good subjective questions". What exactly these attributes means for each community varies.

> Questions are widely studied in linguistics and philosophy of language. In the subfield of pragmatics, questions are regarded as illocutionary acts which raise an issue to be resolved in discourse. In approaches to formal semantics such as alternative semantics or inquisitive semantics, questions are regarded as the denotations of interrogatives, and are typically identified as sets of the propositions which answer them.

If you are willing to go deep about the different type of *questions*, you might be interested in

- [English Language and Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/)

  > Q&A for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts
- [Linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/)

  > Q&A for professional linguists and others with an interest in linguistic research and theory

## Purpose of Stack Exchange Questions

SE questions are closer to [Inquiry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inquiry) (links and formatting not included)

> An inquiry (also spelled as enquiry in British English)[a] is any process that has the aim of augmenting knowledge, resolving doubt, or solving a problem. A theory of inquiry is an account of the various types of inquiry and a treatment of the ways that each type of inquiry achieves its aim.

Each Stack Exchange **community**, as a [community of inquiry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Community_of_inquiry), has its own *process that has the aim of augmenting knowledge, resolving doubt, or solving a problem*. All SE communities use the same "implementation model" / "template": there is a post called *question* which might have none, one or multiple posts called *answers*. During this process there might be *flags*, *votes*, *comments*, *chat messages* and *meta posts* to help clarify, improve and even delete *questions* and *answers* known as **moderation**. Post are *moderated* by the community. The specific working details varies on each **community**.

## Conclusion

Please checkout [**How to ask a good question**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) from the Help Center of the *community* were you might think that this *seed question* (conversation starter) might be well received. Below there is a list of communities that might be related. You might have to review their **tour**, **What topics can I ask about here?** and their per-site meta to have a precise knowledge about what each community want

- **Computer Sciences**: If you want to go deep into the science behind how computers and Internet works. https://cs.stackexchange.com/tour.
- **Computer Science Educators**: If you want to go deep into the science behind how computers and Internet works as self-learner. *Computer Science Educators*, the main audience of this site, might help you to create a self-learning plan. https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/tour.
- History of Science and Mathematics: If your are able to write this as a practical detailed question about **history of science and math**. https://hsm.stackexchange.com/tour
- Stack Overflow: If you are able to write this as a practical, detailed question about **programming**. https://stackoverflow.com/tour.
- Super User: If you are able to write this as a practical, detailed question about using **computer hardware and software as end-user**. https://superuser.com/tour.
- Web Applications: If you are able to write this as a practical, detailed question about using **web applications as end-user**. https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour.

## Related

### FAQ

- [Stack Exchange Moderator FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/118972/)
- [What can I do when getting “This question body does not meet our quality standards”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92074/)
- [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598/)

### Discussions

## [terminology](/questions/tagged/terminology)

- [Are Stack Exchange sites forums?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92107/)

## [tour](/questions/tagged/tour)

- [Is there a rule of thumb for objective questions asked out of curiosity?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164436/)
- [What are the review queues, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161390/)

## [close-reasons](/questions/tagged/close-reasons)[question-quality](/questions/tagged/question-quality)

- [Should Stack Exchange in general be awarding "A"s for Effort?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210840/)

## [asking-questions](/questions/tagged/asking-questions)[help-center-proposed](/questions/tagged/help-center-proposed)

- [Good Subjective and Knowledge Questions vs Problems You Face](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298746/)
- [Let's improve the "How do I ask a good question?" page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/381380/)

### Feature requests

- ["Title-only" questions (i.e. questions without body) should be allowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66119/)